# Query to calculate multiple sums between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Given I have the following table of employees:

```
| name    | company  |
|---------|----------|
| John    | Tesco    |
| Anna    | Tesco    |
| James   | Shopo    |
| Jessica | Salsbury |
```

and their bank transactions:

```
| seller  | buyer   | money |
|---------|---------|-------|
| John    | James   | 40    |
| James   | Anna    | 20    |
| James   | Jessica | 30    |
| Jessica | James   | 10    |
```

I'd like to create a new table summing up their transactions

```
| company  | incoming | outcoming |
|----------|----------|-----------|
| Tesco    | 20       | 40        |
| Shopo    | 50       | 50        |
| Salsbury | 30       | 10        |
```

But I'm struggling with the `GROUP_BY` clause, being able to calculate incoming and outcoming individually, but can't manage to put up a query that can calculate both at once, without running additional `SELECT` inside of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical `Case .. When` question with *Aggregation*, Use :

```
select e.company, 
       sum(case when e.name = b.buyer then money end ) as incoming,
       sum(case when e.name = b.seller then money end ) as outcoming
  from employees e 
  left outer join bank_transactions b
  on ( e.name in (b.seller, b.buyer ) )
  group by e.company
  order by e.company desc;

  company   incoming    outcoming
   Tesco      20           40
   Shopo      50           50
   Salsbury   30           10
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f91b2/3)

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to this type of problem is splitting up the `transactions` into the incoming and outgoing ones.  This uses `union all`.  Once you've done this, the rest is a `join` and `group by`:

```
with tt as (
      select t.seller as employee, 0 as incoming t.money as outgoing 
      from transactions t
      union all
      select t.buyer as employee, t.money as incoming 0 as outgoing 
      from transactions t
     )
select e.company, sum(incoming) as incoming, sum(outgoing) as outgoing
from tt join
     employees e
     on t.employee = e.name 
group by e.company;
```

Answer (score 1):

First let us understand the problem.
Let's say your first table is 'employees', second is bank_transactions. 
Both seller and buyer are in second table. And both seller and buyer are employees of 
any one of the companies which are in first table.
So let's replicate the second table and keep it as two ,one for buyers and another one for sellers with alias names.

1. bank_transactions as b --for buyers
2. bank_transactions as s --for sellers

So now confusion resolved, sellers will give income for their  company and buyers produces outcome(expenditure).Now the code will be a cake walk as below.

```
    select e.company as company,
    sum(s.money) as income,
    sum(b.money) as outcome 
    from
    employees e
    left outer join
    bank_transactions s
    on(e.name=s.seller)
    left outer join
    bank_transactions b
    on(e.name=b.buyer)
    group by e.company
```